# Updating a vector outside a For Loop based on dataframe column condition

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to update a vector using a for loop and ifelse statements in R, but for reasons that are unclear to me, only the first element of the vector is being updated.

To simplify the question, I've created a simple dataframe:

```
State Year Prop  Norm
OR 2010 0.77 0.9404467
OR 2011 0.75 0.9217675
OR 2012 0.82 1.0000000
OR 2013 0.79 0.9631936
OR 2014 0.79 0.9685990
OR 2015 0.78 0.9494104
OR 2016 0.91 1.1120710
OR 2017 0.93 1.1323377
VA 2010 0.90 0.9269292
VA 2011 0.92 0.9425468
VA 2012 0.97 1.0000000
VA 2013 0.93 0.9523327
VA 2014 0.92 0.9466566
VA 2015 0.89 0.9191078
VA 2016 0.94 0.9668455
VA 2017 0.92 0.9483394
```

What I'm trying to do is simple: for every entry in the "Norm" column, if the value is greater than 1, flag it as "Yes" on a vector I've created outside the loop, else, flag it as "No". Here's my attempt at the code:

```
over_1 = c(rep(NA, length(props$Norm)))
for (i in props$Norm) {
    if(i > 1){
        over_1[i] = "YES"}
    else{
       over_1[i] = "NO"
        }
 }
```

And this is what it's returning:

```
[1] "YES" NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
[18] NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
[35] NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

I was able to get around it by using a more sophisticated sapply function:

```
sapply(props$Norm, function(x) ifelse(x > 1, "YES", "NO"))
```

But would love some help with my for loop, as it's driving me insane.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just `ifelse(props$Norm, "YES", "NO")`? BTW, I think `for` loop is not that common in R since this language is characterized by vectorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal can be achieved by simply `ifelse(props$Norm, "YES", "NO")`. BTW, I think `for` loop is not that common in R since this language is characterized by vectorization.

That said, if you really want to solve this in a `for` loop, you have to figure out what `i` stands for in your iteration. `for (i in props$Norm)`, `i` is the numbers in `props$Norm`, e.g. 0.9404467, 0.9483394, ... Hence it can't be right to assign "YES" or "NO" to `over_1[i]`.

One of the correct way is:

```
for (i in seq_len(length(props$Norm))) {
    if (props$Norm[i] > 1) {
        over_1[i] = "YES"}
    else {
        over_1[i] = "NO"
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, @ytu - this worked perfectly! 
Very much understand your point about not using for loops in R, but I was trying to follow an example for a colleague in which it did.  I ended up suggesting using sapply with an ifelse statement, but not getting the for loop was just really bothering me

Answer (score 0):

To help you stop driving yourself insane, the issue is that i is the values of Norm, and then you are using the value as an index.  You need to change the for loop to go from 1 to the length of the vector.

```
over_1 = c(rep(NA, length(props$Norm)))
for (i in 1:length(props$Norm)) {
  if(props$Norm[i] > 1){
    over_1[i] = "YES"}
  else{
    over_1[i] = "NO"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong because `i` will be greater than 1 since the second iteration.

Comment: @ytu is correct, in addition to changing the loop to go from 1 to the length of the vector, you then need to change it to look at the value of Norm for the position.  I edited my answer, to be correct, but ytu posted the correct answer first.